# Не получается установить библиотеку nlpia, Python

Tags: python, library, install

Команда, которой пользуюсь:

```
pip install nlpia
```

Ошибка:

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

command: 'C:\Users\m_pya\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\m_pya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9c1siv5e\python-Levenshtein\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\m_pya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9c1siv5e\python-Levenshtein\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\m_pya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-eti53jw1'

cwd: C:\Users\m_pya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9c1siv5e\python-Levenshtein\

Complete output (27 lines):

...

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

---

ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-Levenshtein

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

command: 'C:\Users\m_pya\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\m_pya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9c1siv5e\python-Levenshtein\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\m_pya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9c1siv5e\python-Levenshtein\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\m_pya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ud2l0fjc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\m_pya\anaconda3\Include\python-Levenshtein'

cwd: C:\Users\m_pya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9c1siv5e\python-Levenshtein
Complete output (27 lines):

...

building 'Levenshtein._levenshtein' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\m_pya\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\m_pya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9c1siv5e\python-Levenshtein\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\m_pya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9c1siv5e\python-Levenshtein\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\m_pya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ud2l0fjc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\m_pya\anaconda3\Include\python-Levenshtein' Check the logs for full command output.

Скачал с сайта Visual Studio, но не помогло.

Попробовал установить через командную строку, вылезает ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обновляю pip, появляется еще одна ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас точно установлен Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 ? И что значит "скачал"? Скачать мало, установить надо.

Comment: Да, конечно, я установил. У меня стоит версия 14.15.26706

Comment: @MaxPyankov В сообщении об ошибке акцент на самом деле на BuildTools - https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ Оно тоже установлено?

Comment: установил, такая же ошибка